# Lambda inject service + dao

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, aws-lambda

I have an Amazon Lambda (springboot) that is deployed and works fine.

I inject services from external projects (dependency add to pom) this way:

```
@Bean
public SomeExternalService someExternalService() {
    return new SomeExternalService;
}
```

I have to do this because when uploaded to Amazon, @Autowired doesn't work.

Now, from another springboot project (not lambda) I have this service that uses a DAO.

Service

```
@Service
public class StateService  {

@Autowired
private StateRepository repository;

/**
 * Find all {@code State}
 */
public void findSomething(String thing) {
    return repository.findSomething("thing");
}
.....
```

Repository

```
@EnableScan
public interface StateRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<State, String> {
    List<State> findSomething(String thing);
```

When building I get

> Error creating bean with name 'StateService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'repository'

and

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'mypackage.repository.StateRepository'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate.

I inject that service exactly like the others

```
@Bean
public StateService stateService() {
    return new StateService;
}
```

I can't do the same for `StateRepository`.

Comment: If you use `@Autowired` it means that Spring has definition of the bean that your are injecting. In your case I am not sure that Spring is aware of `StateRepository` and this repository is out of the context. Did you try to create repository with `@Bean`?

Answer (score 0):

StateRepository class must have @Component annotation or add it in your @Configuration class as @Bean.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.company")
public class ConfigClass {
   // your @Bean's
   @Bean
   public StateRepository stateRepository() {
       return new StateRepository();
   }
   // now can @Autowired
}
```

Comment: No need, it already has @Service and injecting the service is not a problem. Injecting the repository is. EDIT, I'm trying at the moment

Comment: I meant StateRepository

Comment: Or create bean of StateRepository

Comment: No it doesn't help. It still doesn't find the bean repository when deployed on Amazon

Comment: You have `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and it says only that there are no bean definition using annotation or in xml config. If you have xml config that add it. If you use `@Component` annotation it doesn't need anymore.

Comment: If you use annotation, you have to use `<context:component-scan>` in xml or `@ComponentScan` annotation